# PDF Hides Jquery Model Window in Safari 5.1.7

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, safari

Actually I want to show the modal window over pdf and its working well in IE, Chrome & Mozilla Firefox but its not working on Safari 5.1.7

So Will any 1 please help me to find some solution on this ? I am getting this issue on Windows Operating System i.e XP, Windows 8 & Windows 7.

Here is my JS Fiddle link : http://jsfiddle.net/xdrc1nou/

Below is my code as well

**HTML**

```
<div id="divHover">try me</div>
<div id="divHoverChild">hello</div>
<iframe id="ifBG" src="about:blank"></iframe>
<iframe id="ifPDF" src="http://bitcoin.org/bitcoin.pdf"></iframe>
```

**Javascript**

```
 $().ready(function () {
      var $child = $("#divHoverChild");
      var $ifBG = $("#ifBG");

        $("#divHover").mouseover(function () {
           $child.slideDown();
           $ifBG.slideDown();
        })
       $child.mouseout(function () {
           $child.slideUp();
           $ifBG.slideUp();
       });
   });
```

Comment: I don't see your PDF in your example. Its blank.

Answer (score 0):

It will be quite difficult to find someone with OSX Lion running Safari 5.1 to have an answer for your question (that's almost 3 versions back, with Yosemite just around the corner), and a world-wide usage of less than 0.5% of the browser.

With that in mind this answer gives you some pointers, it has not been tested by me.

In general when embedded iframes don't play nicely with the overlays on a page a common solution is applying these styles to the problematic iframes:

`<iframe id="ifPDF" src="http://bitcoin.org/bitcoin.pdf" style="position: relative; z-index: -1;></iframe>`

See if this does it.

A less elegant solution would be to hide the problematic iframes when overlays are triggered to be shown, and therefore avoid the overlap (since the overlapping element is gone).

Just for the record in Safari 7 it works perfectly, just like in the other modern browsers you mentioned to be functioning OK.

Comment: thanks for your reply... But I don't have the Mac Machine @ my end but I am getting this issue on Windows Operating System I.E : 8.0, 7.0 & XP

Comment: And have you tried this solution i proposed with relative positioning and negative zindex and it did not work in IE?

Answer (score -1):

What about using object and ember:

```
<object src="http://yoursite.com/the.pdf" width="700px" height="700px" style="position: relative; z-index: -1;">
    <embed src="http://yoursite.com/the.pdf" style="position: relative; z-index: -1;">
    </embed>
</object>
```

I can't test too. I am running Linux.

Comment: If doesn't work, try also by putting the div after the pdf, and then set its position using jquery, I think that should do the trick.